# Using DeviceCapabilities with pywin32

Tags: python, printing, pywin32

I want to change the tray of a printer by using python. I try to use the following code to retrieve information about the printer and its values:

```
import win32print
x = win32print.DeviceCapabilities('Name of my printer', '192.168.x.x', DC_BINS)
print (x)
```

DC_BINS is supposed to give me a sequence of int. Each belongs to a different tray. However, when I try to run this, the program says that "DC_BINS" is not defined. What am I doing wrong? I am fairly new with python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code corrected:

```py
import win32print
import win32con
x = win32print.DeviceCapabilities('Name of my printer', '192.168.x.x', win32con.DC_BINS)
print (x)
```

code that lists all printers, local and remote, and theirs capabilities:

```
import win32print
from win32con import *

DC_CONSTANTS = [
    DC_BINNAMES, DC_BINS, DC_COLLATE, DC_COLORDEVICE, DC_COPIES, DC_DRIVER,
    DC_DUPLEX, DC_ENUMRESOLUTIONS, DC_EXTRA, DC_FIELDS,
    DC_FILEDEPENDENCIES, DC_MAXEXTENT, DC_MEDIAREADY, DC_MEDIATYPENAMES,
    DC_MEDIATYPES, DC_MINEXTENT, DC_ORIENTATION, DC_NUP, DC_PAPERNAMES,
    DC_PAPERS, DC_PAPERSIZE, DC_PERSONALITY, DC_PRINTERMEM, DC_PRINTRATE, DC_PRINTRATEPPM,
    DC_PRINTRATEUNIT, DC_SIZE, DC_STAPLE, DC_TRUETYPE, DC_VERSION,
]


def DC_INFO(constant):
    for a_global in globals().keys():
        if a_global.startswith("DC_") and globals().get(a_global) == constant:
            return a_global
    return "DC_UNKONWN"


for printer in win32print.EnumPrinters(win32print.PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL | win32print.PRINTER_ENUM_CONNECTIONS):
    print printer
    for constant in DC_CONSTANTS:
        try:
            x = win32print.DeviceCapabilities(printer[2], '', constant)
            print "\t", DC_INFO(constant), x
        except:
            pass
```

I would recommend using an IDE for python, good IDE will mark unknown symbols and suggest where to import those from (like PyCharm does).